# How to protect private blockchain with public blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

Private blockchain has the risk of 51% attack, while public blockchain is pretty safe. 
So can we protect private chain with public chain? 
I got an idea, that we can save block height and block hash, every 100 block.
We save 1,101,201... block height and hash on public chain, and we verify it. 
But it still has risk, before 101 block is protected, 2-99 blocks still have risk.
Is there a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way do it is the correct way. You may either store hash of your Nth block or just store hash every day (or hour) in public chain.

I have recently reviewed Exonum framework (https://exonum.com/) and its Anchoring feature is similar to what you have made.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the possibility to encrypt your data inside a public blockchain. This way you can benefit of the extra security of the public blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

Protection of a Private Blockchain should include security for data at rest, data in motion, metadata and associate aspects. Data in motion can be protected using secure protocols such as TLS and SSL. Data at rest can be secured using state of the art encryption algorithms and digital signatures ( Lampart Signature, Merkle Signatures etc. ). Data at rest includes Block Headers, Block Metadata and Transaction information. Additional layer of security for a Private Blockchain can be provided by using Certificate Authorities.

Answer (score 0):

In a public blockchain, it is important to give admittance to an incorporated power to administer the whole organization, consequently making it a private blockchain now. In a private blockchain, any individual who is managing the organization can adjust or alter any exchanges as indicated by their necessities.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).